# How to pass HTML to shell?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to pass HTML of an existing website to shell as a parameter for a script, but I'm not sure how to properly escape it.

Enclosing it in single or double quotes doesn't work as there are characters such as '$' or '!' , which the shell interprets literally.

Comment: Are you passing it by hand or via a script? And to what command?

Comment: Using NodeJS' child_process.exec to pass it to shell. Have tried it by hand as well, but I keep getting errors like: Syntax error: redirection unexpected.

Comment: As for why it's tagged regex, I thought I needed regex to properly escape the html.

Comment: A programmer has a problem. "I know," he says, "I'll use a regular expression!" Now he has two problems.

Comment: What @WilliamPursell is trying to say is: it is not possible to parse HTML using regex. You will have to come up with another solution.

Comment: Can you give a small sample of what you are trying to pass?

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice to pipe files into shell scripts for this case.

Easy version: write out the content into a temporary file and invoke your shell script with the filename. Your shell script reads the input and deletes the file afterwards.

If you pipe the input into the file, you don't need the temporary file.

Comment: Also, use the `trap` command within the shell script to delete the temp file.  `tmpfile=/tmp/foo.$$; trap "rm -f $tmpfile" 0 1 2 5 15` is one of my favourite lines.